# Attempted Nexus 6P bootloop fix, then factory reset, now won't boot at all

Tags: factory-reset, boot-loop, nexus-6p

My Nexus 6P started bootlooping and since it was out of warranty neither Google or Huawei could help me. I researched online and found the following solution: https://www.xda-developers.com/nexus-6p-bootloop-fix/

I followed the instructions and was able to get it all installed but when it came to reboot I got stuck on the Google logo for over an hour.

I then did a factory reset from recovery mode and now the device gets to the animated loading screen but always fails. It says "Can't load Android system. Your data may be corrupt..." Even after multiple clearing of the caches and data I can't load the phone.

I can no longer see the device under adb or fastboot and I am sure it is because USB Debugging is no longer set. I can't set this again because I can't get into the device. The Bootloader is still unlocked.

What options do I have?

EDIT: The recovery mode states "Supported API: 3"

[image: Message after failed boot]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it using the following:

1. After failing to boot select "Retry"
2. Immediately press power and down volume to enter bootloader
3. Enter Recovery
4. Reload bootloader from Recovery
5. It is now able to be seen by fastboot
6. Downloaded the latest flash image from Google
7. Ran the flash-all.sh

And then it worked. I immediately went in and set up USB-debugging